# open shell bash permission denied

Tags: ros, bash, permission, environment, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Each time I open a new shell window, I get the following:

```
“source: command not found
bash: /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash: Permission denied
```

I get this problem trying to setup ROS Groovy environment on Ubuntu 12.10

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59413/open-shell-bash-permission-denied/) by [alfre7ra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4551/alfre7ra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please post the relevant lines you added to your `~/.bashrc` (or other bash startup script). Looks like a typo.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2